# Variable match in several worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

In my machineconfigurator I have the following code below which worked fine when I had all data for the machines in the same worksheets as the ComboBox2, but NOW I have reorganized the data and divided them over 10 different worksheets. This means one worksheet With items for each machinemodell.

NOW, my problem is this, how do I adjust the code below so that it will search and match in column AG in ALL the 10 sheets and not just the current sheet?

I tried using IF statement and Case statement but they simply will not work.

Any tips are most welcome:)

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

Dim vr%
vr = 0
On Error Resume Next
vr = WorksheetFunction.Match(ComboBox2.Value, Columns("AG"), 0)
On Error GoTo 0
If vr = 0 Then Exit Sub
If ComboBox2.Value = "Velg utstyr her" Then Exit Sub
Range("AE" & vr & ":AM" & vr).Copy Destination:=Range("C91").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

End Sub
```

Update 1: (Trying to loop through sheets but not working)

```
 Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

 Dim Current As Worksheet
 Dim vr%

 For Each Current In Worksheets

 vr = 0
 On Error Resume Next
 vr = WorksheetFunction.Match(ComboBox2.Value, Columns("AG"), 0)
 On Error GoTo 0
 If vr = 0 Then Exit Sub
 If ComboBox2.Value = "Velg utstyr her" Then Exit Sub
 Range("AE" & vr & ":AM" & vr).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C91").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

 Next

 End Sub
```

Comment: It's better to keep all your data in one place if it has the same structure. Just add a "model" column. To loop through sheets:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142126

Comment: I had everything in 1 datasheet first but everytime a New machinemodell comes I have to add it to the list and everything becomes so messy after a while. Thats why I thought having one sheet per machinemodell would be easier to administer. I tried loop through sheets but cannot get the code to work. Obviously something is wrong there. See my updated answer for the code I ended up With so far....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim v

    If ComboBox2.Value = "Velg utstyr her" Then Exit Sub

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        v = Application.Match(ComboBox2.Value, sht.Range("AG:AG"), 0)
        If Not IsError(v) Then
            sht.range("AE" & v & ":AM" & v).Copy _
                   Activesheet.Range("C91").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Exit For 'if you only expect one hit
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```